# Match.Groups[].Value returns repeated values

Tags: c#, regex, match, regex-group

The input is `55`, and my regex is `^(5{2})$`. So ideally (at least to me) this should return every string that starts with a 5 and ends with a 5 right?

But when my c# is like the following:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, String.Format(@"{0}", regex));
string outcome = null;

if (match.Success)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < match.Groups.Count; i++)
    {
        outcome += match.Groups[i].Value;
    }
}
```

Why does my string `outcome` returns 5555 instead of 55?

When I remove the brackets from the regex it works perfectly.

Comment: Why do you need to call `String.Format(@"{0}", regex)`? Why can't you just pass the regex string by itself?

Comment: ahh I was going to add /{0}/gi but I forgot it. I am generating the regex from a text input and I want to have a default to avoid re-typing

Comment: Also, your regex doesn't match every string that starts with a 5 and ends with a 5. It only matches the **exact** string `"55"`. The regex you want (without captures) is `^5.*5$`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first item in `match.Groups` contains the entire match that's picked up by your regex. The second item is what's captured in the brackets.

Since the regex and input are essentially the same string `"55"`, you get two identical matches: one for the entire input matched, and one for the capture group (the brackets).

Both of these are concatenated and you get `"55" + "55"`, which is `"5555"`.

Comment: Thank you, I got it :) However, what if I want to retrieve all matches in a string? Say I want each "a" character in the question I asked. How can I do that?

Comment: @Shaokan: You want to use [`Regex.Matches()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx) instead (notice the plural).

Comment: Yeah I was about to write that I found the solution :) Thanks BoltClock :)